# How to practice Dart projects without using Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-web, dart-null-safety, google-codelab

I'm learning Dart since I soon want to use Futter for different personal projects, but now that I've gone through this interesting [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=F3JuuYuOUK4), I'd like to develop small projects directly using the language and libraries that are in puv.deb.

So far I have only found this [exercise](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FuK1VhrCPzg) which I found very interesting, but all the other projects I find always directly use Flutter. I have also already managed to do the Codelab and other exercises on the Dart website.

**What types of projects could you migrate from other languages to try to implement in Dart?
I would appreciate links to websites or videos where they develop projects in Dart**

Comment: I am also interested in Dart development / examples without using Flutter. Did you manage to find any good resources?